# 2D median filtering in CUDA: how to efficiently copy global memory to shared memory

Tags: filter, cuda, median, gpu-shared-memory

I'm trying to do a median filter with a window `x*y` where `x` and `y` are odd and parameters of the program.

My idea is first see how many threads I can execute in a single block and how much shared memory I have avaliable, like this:

```
void cudaInit(int imgX, int imgY, int kx, int ky, int* cudaVars){
        int device;
        int deviceCount;
        cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;

            cudaGetDevice(&device);
            cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, device);
        int kxMed = kx/2;
        int kyMed = ky/2;
        int n = deviceProp.maxThreadsPerBlock;
        while(f(n,kxMed,kyMed)>deviceProp.sharedMemPerBlock){
            n = n/2;
        }

        cudaVars[0] = n;
        cudaVars[1] = imgX/cudaVars[0];
        cudaVars[2] = imgY/cudaVars[0];
     }
    }



void mediaFilter_gpuB(uchar4* h_img,int width, int height, int kx, int ky){

    assert(h_img!=NULL && width!=0 && height!=0);
        int dev=0;
    cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
    //DEVICE
    uchar4* d_img;
    uchar4* d_buf;

    int cudaVars[3]={0};
    cudaInit(width,height,kx,ky,cudaVars);
checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**) &(d_img), width*height*sizeof(unsigned char)*4));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**) &(d_buf), width*height*sizeof(unsigned char)*4));

    cudaGetDevice(&dev);
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp,dev);
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(d_img, h_img, width*height*sizeof(uchar4), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    dim3 dimGrid(cudaVars[1],cudaVars[2],1);
    dim3 threads(cudaVars[0],1,1);
    mediaFilterB<<<dimGrid,threads,f(cudaVars[0],kx/2,ky/2)>>>(d_buf,d_img,width,height, kx,ky,cudaVars[0]);

    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(h_img, d_buf, width*height*sizeof(uchar4), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(d_img));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(d_buf));

}
__device__ void fillSmem(int* sMem, uchar4* buf, int width, int height, int kx, int ky){
    int kyMed=ky/2;
    int kxMed=kx/2;
    int sWidth = 2*kxMed+gridDim.x;
    int sHeight =2*kyMed+gridDim.x;
    int X = blockIdx.x*gridDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    int Y = blockIdx.y*gridDim.y;
    int j=0;
    while(threadIdx.x+j < sHeight){
        for(int i=0;i<sWidth;i++){
            sMem[threadIdx.x*gridDim.x+gridDim.x*j+i] = buf[X + i +  (threadIdx.x + Y)*width + j*width].x;
        }
        j++;
    }
}
```

For the moment, in the function `mediaFilterB`, I only copy global memory to shared memory, but it takes a lot of time, i.e., about `5` seconds in a image of `8000*8000` pixels. On the other hand, the sequential algorithm without CUDA takes `23` seconds to calculate the median filter of the image.

I know that I`m doing something wrong in the process to copy global memory to shared memory and that my algorithm is very inefficient, but I don't know how I can correct it.

Comment: kx and ky are the size of the window in x and y

Comment: You left out the call to fillSmem(). Shared memory is shared between all threads in a block. The most efficient way to copy global to shared memory is often to have all the threads start out by copying a small section of global to shared memory, in such a way that memory access is coalesced. That is, the threads in a block cooperate on getting the data the block will work on into shared memory, after which a `_syncthreads()` is executed and all the threads in the block start working on the data in shared memory.

Answer (score 3):

I'm providing an answer to this question to remove it from the unanswered list.

The classical example on how using shared memory to improve median filtering with CUDA is the code developed by Accelereyes and made available for download from the following post:

[Median Filtering: CUDA tips and tricks](http://blog.accelereyes.com/blog/2010/03/04/median-filtering-cuda-tips-and-tricks/)

The idea is to allocate a `(BLOCK_WIDTH+2)x(BLOCK_HEIGHT+2)` sized shared memory. At a first step, the outer elements are zeroed. These elements will be filled with global memory values only if they correspond to true image elements, otherwise they will remain zero for padding.

For the sake of convenience, I'm providing below a full working code.

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <fstream>   

using namespace std;

#define BLOCK_WIDTH 16 
#define BLOCK_HEIGHT 16

/*******************/
/* iDivUp FUNCTION */
/*******************/
int iDivUp(int a, int b){ return ((a % b) != 0) ? (a / b + 1) : (a / b); }

/********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECK */
/********************/
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}

/**********************************************/
/* KERNEL WITH OPTIMIZED USE OF SHARED MEMORY */
/**********************************************/
__global__ void Optimized_Kernel_Function_shared(unsigned short *Input_Image, unsigned short *Output_Image, int Image_Width, int Image_Height)
{
    const int tx_l = threadIdx.x;                           // --- Local thread x index
    const int ty_l = threadIdx.y;                           // --- Local thread y index

    const int tx_g = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + tx_l;        // --- Global thread x index
    const int ty_g = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + ty_l;        // --- Global thread y index

    __shared__ unsigned short smem[BLOCK_WIDTH+2][BLOCK_HEIGHT+2];

    // --- Fill the shared memory border with zeros
    if (tx_l == 0)                      smem[tx_l]  [ty_l+1]    = 0;    // --- left border
    else if (tx_l == BLOCK_WIDTH-1)     smem[tx_l+2][ty_l+1]    = 0;    // --- right border
    if (ty_l == 0) {                    smem[tx_l+1][ty_l]      = 0;    // --- upper border
        if (tx_l == 0)                  smem[tx_l]  [ty_l]      = 0;    // --- top-left corner
        else if (tx_l == BLOCK_WIDTH-1) smem[tx_l+2][ty_l]      = 0;    // --- top-right corner
        }   else if (ty_l == BLOCK_HEIGHT-1) {smem[tx_l+1][ty_l+2]  = 0;    // --- bottom border
        if (tx_l == 0)                  smem[tx_l]  [ty_l+2]    = 0;    // --- bottom-left corder
        else if (tx_l == BLOCK_WIDTH-1) smem[tx_l+2][ty_l+2]    = 0;    // --- bottom-right corner
    }

    // --- Fill shared memory
                                                                    smem[tx_l+1][ty_l+1] =                           Input_Image[ty_g*Image_Width + tx_g];      // --- center
    if ((tx_l == 0)&&((tx_g > 0)))                                      smem[tx_l]  [ty_l+1] = Input_Image[ty_g*Image_Width + tx_g-1];      // --- left border
    else if ((tx_l == BLOCK_WIDTH-1)&&(tx_g < Image_Width - 1))         smem[tx_l+2][ty_l+1] = Input_Image[ty_g*Image_Width + tx_g+1];      // --- right border
    if ((ty_l == 0)&&(ty_g > 0)) {                                      smem[tx_l+1][ty_l]   = Input_Image[(ty_g-1)*Image_Width + tx_g];    // --- upper border
            if ((tx_l == 0)&&((tx_g > 0)))                                  smem[tx_l]  [ty_l]   = Input_Image[(ty_g-1)*Image_Width + tx_g-1];  // --- top-left corner
            else if ((tx_l == BLOCK_WIDTH-1)&&(tx_g < Image_Width - 1))     smem[tx_l+2][ty_l]   = Input_Image[(ty_g-1)*Image_Width + tx_g+1];  // --- top-right corner
         } else if ((ty_l == BLOCK_HEIGHT-1)&&(ty_g < Image_Height - 1)) {  smem[tx_l+1][ty_l+2] = Input_Image[(ty_g+1)*Image_Width + tx_g];    // --- bottom border
         if ((tx_l == 0)&&((tx_g > 0)))                                 smem[tx_l]  [ty_l+2] = Input_Image[(ty_g-1)*Image_Width + tx_g-1];  // --- bottom-left corder
        else if ((tx_l == BLOCK_WIDTH-1)&&(tx_g < Image_Width - 1))     smem[tx_l+2][ty_l+2] = Input_Image[(ty_g+1)*Image_Width + tx_g+1];  // --- bottom-right corner
    }
    __syncthreads();

    // --- Pull the 3x3 window in a local array
    unsigned short v[9] = { smem[tx_l][ty_l],   smem[tx_l+1][ty_l],     smem[tx_l+2][ty_l],
                            smem[tx_l][ty_l+1], smem[tx_l+1][ty_l+1],   smem[tx_l+2][ty_l+1],
                            smem[tx_l][ty_l+2], smem[tx_l+1][ty_l+2],   smem[tx_l+2][ty_l+2] };    

    // --- Bubble-sort
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 9; j++) {
            if (v[i] > v[j]) { // swap?
                unsigned short tmp = v[i];
                v[i] = v[j];
                v[j] = tmp;
            }
         }
    }

    // --- Pick the middle one
    Output_Image[ty_g*Image_Width + tx_g] = v[4];
}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    const int Image_Width = 1580;
    const int Image_Height = 1050;

    // --- Open data file
    ifstream is;         is.open("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Project\\Median_Filter\\Release\\Image_To_Be_Filtered.raw", ios::binary );

    // --- Get file length
    is.seekg(0, ios::end);
    int dataLength = is.tellg();
    is.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    // --- Read data from file and close file
    unsigned short* Input_Image_Host = new unsigned short[dataLength * sizeof(char) / sizeof(unsigned short)];
    is.read((char*)Input_Image_Host,dataLength);
    is.close();

    // --- CUDA warm up
    unsigned short *forFirstCudaMalloc; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&forFirstCudaMalloc, dataLength * sizeof(unsigned short)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(forFirstCudaMalloc));

    // --- Allocate host and device memory spaces 
    unsigned short *Output_Image_Host = (unsigned short *)malloc(dataLength);
    unsigned short *Input_Image; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc( (void**)&Input_Image, dataLength * sizeof(unsigned short))); 
    unsigned short *Output_Image; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&Output_Image, dataLength * sizeof(unsigned short))); 

    // --- Copy data from host to device
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(Input_Image, Input_Image_Host, dataLength, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));// copying Host Data To Device Memory For Filtering

    // --- Grid and block sizes
    const dim3 grid (iDivUp(Image_Width, BLOCK_WIDTH), iDivUp(Image_Height, BLOCK_HEIGHT), 1);      
    const dim3 block(BLOCK_WIDTH, BLOCK_HEIGHT, 1); 

    /**********************************************/
    /* KERNEL WITH OPTIMIZED USE OF SHARED MEMORY */
    /**********************************************/

    cudaFuncSetCacheConfig(Optimized_Kernel_Function_shared, cudaFuncCachePreferShared);
    Optimized_Kernel_Function_shared<<<grid,block>>>(Input_Image, Output_Image, Image_Width, Image_Height);
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    // --- Copy results back to the host
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(Output_Image_Host, Output_Image, dataLength, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    // --- Open results file, write results and close the file
    ofstream of2;         of2.open("C:\\Users\\angelo\\Documents\\Project\\Median_Filter\\Release\\Filtered_Image.raw",  ios::binary);
    of2.write((char*)Output_Image_Host, dataLength);
    of2.close();

    cout << "\n Press Any Key To Exit..!!";
    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(Input_Image));

    delete Input_Image_Host;
    delete Output_Image_Host;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks Robert, I have fixed the issue you have raised.

Comment: I have a similar implementation but results on CPU and GPU are not matching. Could you please see  thsi link :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40062053/cuda-gpu-result-different-from-cpu?noredirect=1#comment67400015_40062053