# Image processing : How to perform this function with lockbits

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image-processing

I have a problem. I need to perform this function with lockbits. Please I need help.

```
 public void xPix(Bitmap bmp, int n, Color cx, Color nx)
    {
        try
        {

            for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
            {
                   for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x += (n * 2))
                  {
                       cx = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
                       if (x + n <= bmp.Width - 1) nx = bmp.GetPixel(x + n, y);
                       bmp.SetPixel(x, y, nx);
                       if (x + n <= bmp.Width - 1) bmp.SetPixel(x + n, y, cx);
                  }
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Comment: Use [`LockBitmap`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42602506/3110834) of the linked post.

Comment: Not working can you make a function with your class and send me the code

Comment: "*Not working*" is not a good problem description. If you try the solution and share some code showing what you have tried, and describe more about the problem/error you have, then community users can probably help you.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time using stackoverflow wait i will show you what i tried

Comment: You should show what you tried by updating your question, not adding an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There were lots of things that didn't make sense to me about your code. I fixed the pieces that were preventing an image from appearing and here is the result. I will explain my changes after the code.

```
  public void xPix(Bitmap bmp, int n, Color cx, Color nx)
  {
     var img = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
     byte[] bmpBytes = new byte[Math.Abs(img.Stride) * img.Height];
     System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(img.Scan0, bmpBytes, 0, bmpBytes.Length);

     for (int y = 0; y < img.Height; y++)
     {
        for (int x = 0; x < img.Width; x+=n*2)
        {
           cx = Color.FromArgb(BitConverter.ToInt32(bmpBytes, y * Math.Abs(img.Stride) + x * 4));
           if (x + n <= img.Width - 1) nx = Color.FromArgb(BitConverter.ToInt32(bmpBytes, y * Math.Abs(img.Stride) + x * 4));
           BitConverter.GetBytes(nx.ToArgb()).CopyTo(bmpBytes, y * Math.Abs(img.Stride) + x * 4);
           if (x + n <= img.Width - 1) BitConverter.GetBytes(cx.ToArgb()).CopyTo(bmpBytes, y * Math.Abs(img.Stride) + (x + n) * 4);
        }
     }
     System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bmpBytes, 0, img.Scan0, bmpBytes.Length);
     bmp.UnlockBits(img);
  }

  protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
  {
     base.OnClick(e);
     Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\bluem\Downloads\Default.png");
     for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Width; i++)
     {
        xPix(bmp, new Random().Next(20) + 1, System.Drawing.Color.White, System.Drawing.Color.Green);
     }

     Canvas.Image = bmp;
  }
```

1. There's no such class as `LockBitmap` so I replaced it with the result of a call to `Bitmap.LockBits` directly.
2. The result of `LockBits` does not include functions for `GetPixel` and `SetPixel`, so I did what one normally does with the result of `LockBits` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits?view=netframework-4.7.2) and copied the data into a byte array instead.
3. When accessing the byte data directly, some math must be done to convert the x and y coordinates into a 1-dimensional coordinate within the array of bytes, which I did.
4. When accessing the byte data directly under the `System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb` pixel format, multiple bytes must be accessed to convert between byte data and a pixel color, which I did with `BitConverter.GetBytes`, `BitConverter.ToInt32`, `Color.FromArgb` and `Color.ToArgb`.
5. I don't think it's a good idea to be changing the `Image` in the middle of painting it. You should either be drawing the image directly during the `Paint` event, or changing the image outside the `Paint` event and allowing the system to draw it. So I used the `OnClick` of my form to trigger the function instead.
6. The first random number I got was 0, so I had to add 1 to avoid an endless loop.
7. The `cx` and `nx` parameters never seem to be used as inputs, so I put arbitrary color values in for them. Your `x` and `y` variables were not defined/declared anywhere.

Comment: thanks it worked but still slow how can i make it faster i added parallel.For but still not fast enough

Comment: @AymanBenyahia Why do you have a loop for `i` from `0` to `bmp.Width`? You are already looping through the width of the image with x. Can you somehow combine these loops? It would be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you want faster on-image-action, you can use [Marshall.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy?view=netframework-4.7.2) method with [Parallel.For](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-for-loop)

Why dont use [GetPixel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getpixel) method? Because every time you call it, your ALL image is loaded to memory. GetPixel get one pixel, and UNLOAD all image. And in every iteration, ALL image is loaded to memory (for example, if u r working on 500x500 pix image, GetPixel will load 500x500 times whole pixels to memory). When you work on images with C# (CV stuff), work on raw `bytes` from memory.

I will show how to use with `Lockbits` in [Binarization](http://felixniklas.com/imageprocessing/binarization) because its easy to explain.

```
 int pixelBPP = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(resultBmp.PixelFormat) / 8;

        unsafe
        {
            BitmapData bmpData = resultBmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, resultBmp.Width, resultBmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, resultBmp.PixelFormat);

            byte* ptr = (byte*)bmpData.Scan0; //addres of first line

            int height = resultBmp.Height;
            int width = resultBmp.Width * pixelBPP;

            Parallel.For(0, height, y =>
            {
                byte* offset = ptr + (y * bmpData.Stride); //set row
                for(int x = 0; x < width; x = x + pixelBPP)
                {
                    byte value = (offset[x] + offset[x + 1] + offset[x + 2]) / 3 > threshold ? Byte.MaxValue : Byte.MinValue;
                    offset[x] = value;
                    offset[x + 1] = value;
                    offset[x + 2] = value;

                    if (pixelBPP == 4)
                    {
                        offset[x + 3] = 255;
                    }
                }
            });

            resultBmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        }
```

Now, example with `Marshall.copy`:

```
BitmapData bmpData = resultBmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, resultBmp.Width, resultBmp.Height), 
                                                ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, 
                                                resultBmp.PixelFormat
                                                );


        int bytes = bmpData.Stride * resultBmp.Height;
        byte[] pixels = new byte[bytes];

        Marshal.Copy(bmpData.Scan0, pixels, 0, bytes); //loading bytes to memory
        int height = resultBmp.Height;
        int width  = resultBmp.Width;

        Parallel.For(0, height - 1, y => //seting 2s and 3s
        {
            int offset = y * stride; //row
            for (int x = 0; x < width - 1; x++)
            {
                int positionOfPixel = x + offset + pixelFormat; //remember about pixel format!
                    //do what you want with pixel
                }
            }
        });

       Marshal.Copy(pixels, 0, bmpData.Scan0, bytes); //copying bytes to bitmap
        resultBmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

Remember, when you warking with RAW `bytes` very important is to remember about `PixelFormat`. If you work on `RGBA` image, you need to set up every channel. (for example `offset + x + pixelFormat`). I showed it in `Binarization` example, how to deak with RGBA  image with raw data. If `lockbits` are not fast enough, use `Marshall.Copy`