# Inverse dithering in .NET

Tags: .net, dithering

Given an image that was created with dithering, how can this image be converted back to using a full palette?

It seems .net does not offer any tools for this purpose.

(I'm aware that this mapping is neither unique nor lossless - I'm fine with that)

Comment: Maybe some sort of "blur" filter, to smooth out the pixels?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564955/despeckle-remove-spots-or-dots-from-the-image